# JPA Query Missing alias and column (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following relevant JPA annotated classes in a Spring-Boot JPA enabled project (All Groovy Code):

```
@Entity
abstract class Character {
    @Id
    String id;

    String name;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Episode)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    Collection<Episode> appearsIn;
}

@Entity(name = "Human")
public class Human extends Character {
    String homePlanet;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "favorite_droid_id")
    Droid favoriteDroid;
}

public enum Episode {
    PHANTOM_MENACE,
    ATTACK_OF_THE_CLONES,
    REVENGE_OF_THE_SITH,
    A_NEW_HOPE,
    EMPIRE_STRIKES_BACK,
    RETURN_OF_THE_JEDI,
    THE_FORCE_AWAKENS
}
```

When I attempt to execute the following JPA Query:

```
def query = em.createQuery("from Human h where h.appearsIn in (:episodes)");
query.setParameter("episodes", EnumSet.of(Episode.THE_FORCE_AWAKENS));
def result = query.getResultList();
```

The generated SQL statement does not seem to have the alias to the Character table or the column name for appears_in:

```
select human0_.id as id2_0_, human0_.name as name3_0_, human0_.favorite_droid_id as favorite6_0_, human0_.home_planet as home_pla5_0_ 
from character human0_ 
cross join character_appears_in appearsin1_ 
where human0_.dtype='Human' and human0_.id=appearsin1_.character_id and (. in (?))
```

I have also tried using equals instead of in, with the same behavior:

```
from Human h where h.appearsIn = :episode
```

Produces the following SQL:

```
select human0_.id as id2_0_, human0_.name as name3_0_, human0_.favorite_droid_id as favorite6_0_, human0_.home_planet as home_pla5_0_ 
from character human0_ 
cross join character_appears_in appearsin1_ 
where human0_.dtype='Human' and human0_.id=appearsin1_.character_id and .=?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do "collection IN collection". Invalid JPQL. I would have expected the JPA provider to give a message to that effect

Comment: you can use setParameterList for Collection IN

Comment: What "setParameterList"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is invalid - as @Neil Stockton pointed out, by writing `h.appearsIn in (:episodes)` you are saying "collection in collection" which does not make sense.

You should rather declare a "collection member variable" like this:

```
select distinct h
from Human h 
join h.appearsIn ai
where ai in (:episodes)
```

`ai` represents a single element of `appearsIn` (like an iterator).